# Finding pairs of nodes not having an edge-networkx python

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, graph-theory

I want to find all the possible pairs of nodes that *do not* have an edge connecting them and then check if these pairs of nodes have an edge in another graph. Any suggestions?

Comment: So... what have you got so far?

Comment: No, not homework...working on a research project :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care for performance then you can try:

```
g1Edges = Graph1.edges()
notG1Edges = set()
for a in Graph1.nodes():
    for b in Graph1.nodes():
        if a != b and (a,b) not in g1Edges:
            notG1Edges.add( (a, b) )
# print edges missed in Graph1 and Graph2
print notG1Edges.difference( Graph2.edges_iter() )
```

NOTE1: this is for directed graphs

NOTE2: if you want to find subset of edges from Graph2 not present in Graph1 then suppose it's better to operate on edges from Graph2

Comment: Can u help me out coz the graph i'm working on is not directed... I thought of getting the complement of the graph having edges... intuitively i would get edges amongst all the nodes that do not have an edge...but cant seem to get the code right...could help me out with this...

Comment: Post some of your code, and someone can probably tell you why it doesn't work.